# Output file is corrupted while downloading and merging

Tags: go

everyone.

I'm try to download file parts from web server and merge it into a single file.
Here's how i did it:

```
out, err := os.Create(fileInfo.FileInfo.FileName)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, hash := range fileInfo.FileInfo.FileBlocks {
        keeper := getKeeperByHash(hash.Hash, fileInfo.HasHash)
        log.Println("Downloading", hash.Hash)
        downloadURL := &url.URL{
            Scheme: "http",
            Host:   fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", keeper.Ip, keeper.Port),
            Path:   "file/get",
        }
        param := url.Values{}
        param.Add("hash", hash.Hash)
        downloadURL.RawQuery = param.Encode()
        resp, err := http.Get(downloadURL.String())
        n, err := io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
        log.Println(n)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        resp.Body.Close()
    }
    out.Close()
    hash1, _ := GetFileHashAlt(fileInfo.FileInfo.FileName)
    if hash1 != fileInfo.FileInfo.FileHash {
        log.Println(hash1)
        log.Println(fileInfo.FileInfo.FileHash)

        panic("HASH NOT THE SAME")
    }
    log.Println(hash1)
    log.Println(fileInfo.FileInfo.FileHash)
```

But for the binary files hashes is not the same and file is corrupted. For text files everything is ok.
Where can be the problem?
When i',m uploading and splitting file, i'm checking hashes all the way and it's always the same.

I tried first split files after download and them merge it to a one file, but the problem is still there.

Comment: `I tried first split files after download`, have you checked the file content of each file? You haven't checked the HTTP status code of the response; the request could fail, so you should check the status of the response.

Comment: Yes, i checked content for text files. It's OK. The web server running at localhost, so the response status code was always 200. The problem is always for binary files.

Comment: Have you checked the binary files?

Comment: Yes, it’s binary

Comment: Do you mean that the content of each binary part is correct, but after they are merged into a single file, the single file is incorrect? If this is the case, then it could be the file order is not correct.

Comment: The problem could be that you're not considering the case that each file block may not be aligned with the boundaries of the underlying file system block size; which corrupts on merging blocks. `io.SectionReader` may be a better way in this case.

Comment: @ZekeLu The problem was in content of binary part. I was using Fastify framework as a http server, and it was changing content i was sending to client. I replace it with Express and everything is working fine. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at the server side. Fastify framework was changing file part contents. Replacing it to Express JS solved the problem.